# Synonym for "business infrastructure"

Tags: synonyms

We're internally using the term "business infrastructure" to group a set of modules, like a web site, an administration portal, an e-commerce engine and so on. While nicely accepted by the team, the term is often shorten to "BI", which, in the software industry, already refers to another concept (more precisely, "business intelligence").
We need to find another term, but the synonyms suggested by the dictionaries will not do (we cannot say "business base", "business groundwork", "business underpinning").
Can you suggest a synonym?

Comment: BINF. And 'finely accepted' isn't an acceptable way of saying 'accepted as fine'.

Comment: I'd say 'business structures', but I don't suppose 'BS' will fly!

Comment: These days software people like to throw around the word "stack" for things like this.  The infrastructure consists of a bunch of layers, which constitute a stack.  But again, you run into the "BS" problem.

Comment: @TusharRaj - If BS doesn't work, I don't suppose there's a good pair of words for BM.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: please create an answer so I can accept it. Thank you both for the answer and the correction.

Comment: Maybe the problem is  your use of *Business Infrastructure* incorrectly? What are you describing are **Operational Tools**, which are a part of business infrastructure. I'd say OT has a ring to it.

Comment: @HotLicks I resemble that remark (those are my initials). :)

Comment: It's not unusual for companies to have internal jargon and acronyms that conflict with common industry phrases. It can be confusing for new employees, but they quickly get used to it. There are only so many short acronyms, and there are likely to be pre-existing meanings for most of the ones you might want to use.

Comment: @AcePL: Please create an answer. I have "BINF" and "OT" to choose from. Thank you.

Comment: @Barmar: I completely agree on your take on internal jargon. However there must be clear distinction between internal jargon and logic. That kind of conflict is recipe for disaster. While there is no way to create unambiguous vocabulary in software industry to satisfy everyone, that big divert from commonly accepted definitions is rather uncommon. It's like calling IC engine a car...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business infrastructure is something that covers all kinds of resources that any given company has at it's disposal, including software or other IT solutions. That being said, I think the term you should be going for is **"Operational Tools"**.
It has a ring to as an acronym. And said acronym is not as common as other proposals.

I can also propose **"Business IT Solutions"**... However, this one's short version is, while rather interesting, also somewhat ambiguous? But - if one likes it - why the heck not? ;)